# Importing a Swift module using a C library

Tags: c, linux, swift, curses

I've written a Curses wrapper module by following the instructions of [this page](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/13d682a63ea01246dd119cd4cf5c8d90c030566d/Documentation/SystemModules.md).

However, I do not know how to properly make it work in a module using it.

I have 3 parallel directories: CCurses, CursesWrapper, ModuleUsingCursesWrapper.

CCurses contains an empty Package.swift file and a module.modulemap file containing

```
module CCurses [system] {
    header "/usr/include/curses.h"
    link "curses"
    export *
}
```

CursesWrapper contains a Package.swift file containing.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(dependencies: [.Package(url: "../CCurses", majorVersion: 1)])
```

and a general.swift file containing

```
import CCurses

public func startCurses() -> Void{
    initscr()}

public func getchar() -> Void{
    getch()}

public func endCurses() -> Void{
    endwin()}
```

ModuleUsingCursesWrapper contains a Package.swift file containing

```
import PackageDescription

let package = dependencies: [.Package(url: "../CursesWrapper", majorVersion: 1)])
```

and a main.swift file containing

```
import CursesWrapper

startCurses()
getchar()
endCurses()
```

When running swift build in ModuleUsingCursesWrapper, I get the following output:

```
Cloning Packages/CursesWrapper
Cloning Packages/CCurses
Compiling Swift Module 'CursesWrapper' (1 sources)
Linking Library:  .build/debug/CursesWrapper.a
Compiling Swift Module 'ModuleUsingCursesWrapper' (1 sources)
Linking Executable:  .build/debug/ModuleUsingCursesWrapper
.../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/.build/debug/CursesWrapper.a(general.swift.o): In function `_TF14CursesWrapper11startCursesFT_T_':
.../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/Packages/CursesWrapper-1.0.0/general.swift:5: undefined reference to `initscr'
.../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/.build/debug/CursesWrapper.a(general.swift.o): In function `_TF1CursesWrapper7getcharFT_T_':
.../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/Packages/CursesWrapper-1.0.0/general.swift:8: undefined reference to `getch'
.../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/.build/debug/CursesWrapper.a(general.swift.o): In function `_TF14CursesWrapper9endCursesFT_T_':
.../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/Packages/CursesWrapper-1.0.0/general.swift:11: undefined reference to `endwin'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
< unknown >:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
< unknown :0: error: build had 1 command failures
swift-build: exit(1): [".../Swift/usr/bin/swift-build-tool", "-f", ".../ModuleUsingCursesWrapper/.build/debug/ModuleUsingCursesWrapper.o/llbuild.yaml"]
```

It seems that when compiling ModuleUsingCursesWrapper, the curses functions cannot be found. How can I solve this problem ?

(I'm on Linux)

Comment: Some packagers leave out the link between libcurses.so and libncurses.so (you could change the link parameter to "ncurses" to work around that).

Comment: In fact, I changed to ncursesw before downloading the latest Swift snapshot (December 21, 2015) and it still didn't work at that time.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with your example for awhile on an Ubuntu 14.04 box, I ran into the same error.  After some additional experimentation, I was able to solve it by adding the following to `main.swift`:

```
import CCurses
```

The `Package.swift` file of the module using the wrapper references only CursesWrapper, but if `CCurses` is not imported into `main.swift`, then the undefined reference error occurs.

The need to import dependencies of imported modules can be seen from the link to swift.org that you provided, where a JasPer/JPEG example is discussed.  Strictly speaking, JasPer is not a wrapper around JPEG, but is just another system module, yet the idea is the same: if we import module A that depends on module B, then we should also import module B.

BTW I had to change `public func getchar()` to `public func getChar()` and modify `main.swift` accordingly.  Otherwise I would get `ambiguous use of 'getchar()'` error when compiling `main.swift`.  Evidently it is already defined in `CCurses`, which is no surprise as it is a standard C function.