# Swift Linux. Error: no such module 'Dispatch'

Tags: swift

I use Ubuntu 15.10
I compiled **swift-corelibs-libdispatch**, get file libdispatch.so
But still if I use "import Dispatch" get an error "no such module 'Dispatch'"

How can I add this module to Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to set up a system module for `libdispatch` and use `swift build`.  See https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/13d682a63ea01246dd119cd4cf5c8d90c030566d/Documentation/SystemModules.md on how to use system modules.  This quesion, [Importing a Swift module using a C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421200/importing-a-swift-module-using-a-c-library), may also come in handy.

I'm sure there are other ways, too.  You should be able to use swift interpreter or swift compiler (`swiftc`), but I can't think of a way to do that off the top of my head.