# HTTP Request in Swift without NSURLRequest

Tags: linux, swift, httprequest

We want to make HTTP(S) requests (GET) to call an API. The Problem is, NSURLRequest is (at the moment) not implemented in the Foundation for Linux (https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSURLRequest.swift).

Are there any other possibilities to create an HTTP request?

Comment: [curl mapping for swift](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/CCurl) IBM has a swift package for curl. I just can't figure out how to get it to do a simple GET request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice project called **HTTPMiddleware** that can be useful, it's just a middleware framework but it works well.

Here's a code example:

```
import HTTP
import HTTPMiddleware

struct Middleware: HTTPRequestMiddlewareType {
    func respond(request: HTTPRequest) -> HTTPRequestMiddlewareResult {
        // You can change the request and pass it forward
        return .Next(request)

        // Or you can respond early and bypass the chain
        return .Respond(HTTPResponse(statusCode: 404, reasonPhrase: "Not Found"))
    }
}

struct Responder: HTTPResponderType {
    func respond(request: HTTPRequest) -> HTTPResponse {
        // May or may not be called depending on the middleware
        return HTTPResponse(statusCode: 200, reasonPhrase: "OK")
    }
}

let request = HTTPRequest(method: .GET, uri: URI(path: "/"))
let chain = Middleware() >>> Responder()
let response = chain.respond(request)
```

Here is the official [page](https://github.com/paulofaria/Middleware), you can also find a **JSON** parser in the sources that can be useful for common requests.
The installation requires only the **uri_parser**.

Comment: I really wonder why there isn't a single Swift Package with documentation. If you look at golang, you will have to look long and hard to find one without full docs. Anyway, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Is only swift 2.2 and hasn't seen activity in 6 months. So not very useful anymore.

Comment: Well the 100+ build errors I get say it doesn't... I'm sorry but a package that is only Swift 2.2 and hasn't been updated in 6 months is not a good choice for production software

Comment: Im sorry but what swift version you use? Actually the swift 2.2 is always the more stable, Have you an old version? And what is your distro? Swift releases: https://github.com/apple/swift/branches You dont see any activity for now in the official page because there arent founded issues.

Comment: I have dockerized everything I do in Swift for linux. My current base image is `ibmcom/swift-ubuntu:latest`. This uses Swift 3.0 and runs Ubuntu 15 if I'm not mistaken. On my host machine I run OSX with the official swift 2.2

Comment: Sir, Swift 3.0 it's just a preview now,  I dont know about your compilation errors, I've slackware and I havent any issue. I hope that will come some news with the next Apple WWDC . Good luck

Comment: No problem, I hope you find some better

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because your answer seems to have helped the most people. I found a solution to my specific issue (added it as an answer). Thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 3):

Consider following solution based on ccurl library:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2504173/CurlSampleApp.tar.gz

I did it on Ubuntu 14.04

Swift 3.0 - latest development version:
https://swift.org/builds/development/ubuntu1404/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-06-a/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-06-a-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz

Following package and instructions worked fine in general:

https://swiftpkgs.ng.bluemix.net/package/SwiftOnTheServer/CCurl

But in order to fix compilation errors I had to modify `sots_curl.h` in CCurl package. Following line was added:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

For the app building you need to perform following in the app folder:

```
swift build
```

For app running you need to perform following command in the app folder:

```
.build/debug/app
```

Hope it helps. Ask questions if any :)

Comment: I am now trying out [bluemix-simple-http-client-swift](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-simple-http-client-swift.git) It is a wrapper around CCurl and even though there sample code is bad, if you modify it to compile it works really well.

Comment: [pull request with corrected sample code](https://github.com/romainmenke/bluemix-simple-http-client-swift/tree/patch-2)

Answer (score 2):

Considering that Swift on Linux is fast-evolving work in progress, the best approach, I think, is to hold off doing any serious development until the situation is more stable.  Even if you overcome the obstacle of making HTTP requests, there will likely be other unpleasant surprises due to the technology being immature on Linux.

However, if this is just a matter of curiosity and learning, here are some ideas, even though I haven't tried them myself:

- Maybe calling CoreFoundation C APIs directly will work.
- Write a C wrapper, that provides the interface you need, using good old C network APIs.  This approach would probably require more effort than the others, as you will be re-inventing a lot of wheels.
- Write a C wrapper, but wrap a higher-level C library that works with URLs; libcurl comes to mind.

Regardless of which of these approaches you take, you will need to interface with C code.  One way to do this is to use system modules, see [Importing a Swift module using a C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421200/importing-a-swift-module-using-a-c-library) as a possible starting point.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. you are right, perhaps the best answer is to wait. a c module can be a option, perhaps there is an easy to use api.

Answer (score 2):

Since mid-2017 there is IBM's [SwiftyRequest](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/SwiftyRequest) library, which works on both Linux and iOS. I've tried it on Linux and seems to work fine.

Making a request looks like this (adapted an example from docs):

```
import SwiftyRequest

let request = RestRequest(method: .get, url: "http://myApiCall/hello")
request.responseString() { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let result):
        print("Success")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Failure")
    }
}
```

If you're using JSON for the responses, it can even construct you an object based on a "schema" you provide (have a look at `.responseObject` and `JSONDecodable` in the [tests](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/SwiftyRequest/blob/master/Tests/SwiftyRequestTests/SwiftyRequestTests.swift) for examples).

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but maybe useful to someone:

I only needed `NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL)` so I ended up writing a wrapper for KituraNet that does this with a closure. I just check if there is data and return that.

Because `NSURL` is far from fully implemented I also decided to pass the url as a `String` for now.

It's not a replacement for `NSURLRequest`, just the good old convenience of `NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL)`

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-net.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 15),
```

---

```
import KituraNet

extension NSData {

  public static func contents(ofUrl urlString:String, completionHandler:((data:NSData?) -> Void)) {

    let request = HTTP.request(urlString) { (response) in

      guard let response = response else {
        completionHandler(data: nil)
        return
      }

      let responseData = NSMutableData()
      do {
        try response.readAllData(into: responseData)
        completionHandler(data: responseData)
        return
      } catch {
        completionHandler(data: nil)
        return
      }
    }
    request.end()
  }
}
```